# how to get exact DIV value for alert

Tags: javascript, html

I just wonder that how I can get exact div value?
There are about 10 buttons for each  div id= cart value=1 / div id=cart value=2 ....... but when I click each buttons, all I can see is just  1 , I increased index tho.
How can I handle this problem?

```html
    <%
     String url = "https://store.pinkfong.com/category/soundbook/";
    
     String line = "";
     int index = 0;
    
     try {
    
      Document doc;
    
      doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    
      Elements media4 = doc.select("div.container ul li img ");
    
      Elements media5 = doc.select(".title ");
    
      for (int i = 0; i < media5.size(); i++) {
       Element src1 = media4.get(i);
       Element src2 = media5.get(i);
       index++;
    
       String templine = "<div id = 'cart' value= " + index + " >"
         + "<button id='button1' onclick='bb();'>button</button>" + src1.toString();
    
       line += templine;
       templine = src2.toString();
       line += templine + "</div>";
      }
    
     } catch (IOException e) {
    
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    
      e.printStackTrace();
    
     }
    %>
    
    <script>
     function bb() {
      var num = document.getElementById('cart').getAttribute('value');
      alert(num);
     }
    </script>
    <body>
    
     <%=line%>
    </body>
```

Comment: you should use `class="cart"` instead of `id`. Generally, `class` is for repetitive elements and `id` marks a single element. Every `id`
 should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID should be unique. `document.getElementById` will always return the first result, so in your case, it's only matching the first "cart".

To solve that, I'd just the `id` from the `<div>` and change the `bb` function slightly. Start by passing in the button that was clicked.

```
<%
// ...

String templine = "<div value= " + index + " >"
        + "<button id='button" + index + "' onclick='bb(this);'>button</button>" + src1.toString();

// ...

%>
```

Then your `bb` function should accept that button and get it's parent's `value`:

```
function bb(button) {
    var num = button.parentNode.getAttribute('value');
    alert(num);
}
```

This is considered an old-school approach and modern-day developers would use "event delegation" to handle this instead, but that may be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: perfect solution! I gotta learn more about some codes u gave. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using ID. So it gets the first item with the ID of 'cart'.